# Python nested IF statements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a script that checks a folder for files older than 7 days and deletes them, but only if a file younger than 1 day from "now" exists.

So, if a new file has been created that is less than 1 day old, then delete all files older than seven days.

This is my script -

```
import os, time
path = r"C:\Temp" #working path#
now = time.time()
for f in os.listdir(path):
 f = os.path.join(path, f)
 if os.stat(os.path.join(path, f).st_mtime < now -1 * 86400 and\ #checking new file#
 if os.stat(os.path.join(path,f)).st_mtime < now - 7 * 86400: #checking old files#
  if os.path.isfile(f):
   os.remove(os.path.join(path, f)
```

I'm getting syntax errors in my line checking for old files. Am I not indenting correctly, is this an invalid way to code this? A program creates a new file each day. This script checks to see if that file has been created, and if this is true, then checks for files older than seven days and deletes them. I don't understand the syntax error, the logic is correct, am I right?

Comment: your paths are wrong...the first line makes the path the joined version including the full path... then you join the path to it in your stats... so you are doing `os.stat("C:\TempC:\Temp\somefile.txt")`

Comment: and `and` shouldn't be followed by `if`, i think

Comment: Qnan is actually telling you why your getting the error ... mine will tell you why your code doesnt work ...  are you taking a class right now? It seems like your missing some core concept stuff...If not I would recommend a class or doing some good tutorials online ..

Comment: Furthermore, your second if (the one incorrectly following an and) is superseded by your first if:  if a < x - 7y, then by definition, a < x - y.

Comment: So I should just be writing "if os.stat(f).st_mtime"? Now that Qnan points that out, I see it and I feel silly about that. And no, I'm not taking a class, I'm just a raw beginner that learns better by doing and asking questions about what I did. I need some classes, though. Online tutorials are a lot more confusing without somebody to look at say "Can you put that in English, please".

Comment: Jodaka, so what do I need to change? Freaking algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os, time
path = r"C:\Temp" #working path#
now = time.time()
old_files = [] # list of files older than 7 days
new_files = [] # list of files newer than 1 day
for f in os.listdir(path):
    fn = os.path.join(path, f)
    mtime = os.stat(fn).st_mtime
    if mtime > now - 1 * 86400:
        # this is a new file
        new_files.append(fn)
    elif mtime < now - 7 * 86400:
        # this is an old file
        old_files.append(fn)
    # else file between 1 and 7 days old, ignore
if new_files:
    # if there are any new files, then delete all old files
    for fn in old_files:
        os.remove(fn)
```

Comment: I like this. This worked. A lot longer than I thought it would be, but it worked. I just need to keep writing scripts, I'll get better at it. Thank you. Any suggestions on what modules to use to make it create a log file if it fails?

Comment: @user1681573 - use the `logging` module.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code,

- You are missing a closing bracket in the following line:

  if os.stat(os.path.join(path, f).st_mtime < now -1 * 86400

Should actually be:

```
if os.stat(os.path.join(path, f)).st_mtime < now -1 * 86400
```

1. There is no need for **and if**

   if os.stat(os.path.join(path, f).st_mtime < now -1 * 86400 and\ #checking new file#
   if os.stat(os.path.join(path,f)).st_mtime < now - 7 * 86400:

it should be:

```
if os.stat(os.path.join(path, f)).st_mtime < now -1 * 86400 and\ #checking new file#
os.stat(os.path.join(path,f)).st_mtime < now - 7 * 86400:
```

1. Try to use Brackets for your statements i.e

   if os.stat(os.path.join(path, f)).st_mtime < (now -1 * 86400) and os.stat(os.path.join(path,f)).st_mtime < (now - 7 * 86400):

Comment: Other than those minor mistakes, my code would/should have worked? So my math checks out?